# Длина event(событие) в диапазоне(range) Fullcalendar scheduler

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте,
Работаю с Fullcalendar scheduler.

Длина event(событие) в диапазоне(range), то есть, есть max and min duration для event(событие), нужно чтобы пересечение(overlap) было в приделах max and min duration по максимуму. То есть, если есть свободное место которое удовлетворяет минимуму и максимуму событие можно его вложить в это место по максимуму сколько пространства есть.

Как можно это организовать?
Большое спасибо.

Comment: Почистите лишние англицизмы и приведите пример что надо и что есть.

Comment: Вопрос требует уточнения.

Comment: @Sublihim, что именно ты хочешь уточнить?